# Why are there two network indicators with ubuntu-desktop in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager, indicator

I installed Kubuntu 13.10 32 bit on my Yoga 2 Pro and after some days all window decorations were gone and I couldn't repair that, so I decided to install

```
aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

and use Ubuntu ever since.

the only strange thing is, that there are two Network controls somehow on my system now in the top right corner:

[image]

the kright one, you can mark and unmark all wifi networks and hafe "Wi-Fi settings" (unlocalized in english) which does nothing, when you click on it.

The left one is locallized and looks like this:
[image]

"Bearbeiten" means settings and works fine

How can I find out what those are?

Those are the relevant packages installed, i think:

```
dpkg -l|gawk '{ print $1 " " $2}'|egrep "network|-nm"
ii gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
ii glib-networking:i386
ii glib-networking-common
ii glib-networking-services
ii indicator-network
ii kdenetwork-filesharing
ii libnetworkmanagerqt0
ii libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager:i386
ii libqt4-network:i386
ii libqt5network5:i386
ii libqtscript4-network:i386
ii network-manager
ii network-manager-gnome
ii network-manager-pptp
ii network-manager-pptp-gnome
ii plasma-nm
```

complete list here: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/58d8785561c5ac023192

---

EDIT

If I start the `system manager` I see there are the processes

```
nm-applet
```

and

```
indicator-network-service
```

It seems they are not working together well?

How can I remove the indicator-network-service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `nm-applet` from loading at startup of Unity by the use of this command:

```
 sudo sed --in-place 's/NotShowIn=KDE/NotShowIn=Unity/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```